# DNS: can't query domain

Tags: bind, nslookup, dig

For some reason I can't query specific domains.
Although `dig` works as it should, `nslookup` doesn't.

`home1:/# dig +trace www.capital.gr`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> +trace www.capital.gr
;; global options: +cmd
.                       514903  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       514903  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 0 ms

gr.                     172800  IN      NS      gr-m.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      estia.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      gr-us.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      grdns.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      gr-aix.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      grdns-at.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      grdns-br.ics.forth.gr.
gr.                     172800  IN      NS      grdns-de.denic.de.
;; Received 461 bytes from 128.63.2.53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 135 ms

capital.gr.             10800   IN      NS      ns0.internet.gr.
capital.gr.             10800   IN      NS      ns1.internet.gr.
;; Received 109 bytes from 199.4.28.219#53(gr-us.ics.forth.gr) in 201 ms

www.capital.gr.         86400   IN      CNAME   capital.atoll.gr.
;; Received 60 bytes from 62.1.1.62#53(ns0.internet.gr) in 2 ms
```

The above worked!

```
home1:/# nslookup www.capital.gr
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

The above didn't work!

Anyway, why do I face this different behavior from the same host?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after removing the command:

query-source    port 53;